# Methods for solving for partial fraction coefficients.

Tags: education, partial-fractions

When I present partial fraction decomposition, there are typically two approaches to solve for the coefficients of the fractions:

- Clear the fractions, multiply out the products, and equate coefficients (of the indeterminate).  This leads to a system of linear equations.
- Clear the fractions, and substitute several values for the indeterminate.  This leads to a different system of linear equations.

Is there a good reason to prefer one method over the another?  Is there another situation (perhaps in differential equations) that I'm not thinking of where one method is superior to the other?  Is there a good pedagogical reason to present one method over another?

Considering the theory of quotient fields and polynomials, both methods should work (provided the partial fractions have been computed correctly so that a solution exists).

I may consider also asking this question on Mathematics Educators, but I thought to start here.

Comment: The second method is usually faster and better accepted. Actually, I know that engineers have a mnemonic rule to do this kind of computations super-quickly (those things date back to Olivier Heaviside, as far as I know). I don't know the details, unfortunately.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I agree that the second method is often faster.  What do you mean by "better accepted" (both methods provide correct answers, so who accepts that method more)?

Comment: I present both. The first shows what's *really* going on - two polynomials are identical provided their coefficients agree. The second shows a nice "trick" that generalizes elsewhere - if a statement is true for every $x$, then it's true for any particular $x$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I wanted to say that the students are more satisfied by the second method. (This, of course, is only my personal opinion).